# Кое-где в коде нужна помощь. Совсем маленькая

Tags: c++, сортировка

Даны два массива длины 2N.В массиве А числа , причем А[i]<=A[i+N] (в исходном условии в первой части массива координаты начала отрезка, а во второй половине концы отрезков).Массив В взаимосвязан с массивом А. Там, где в А начало отрезка, в В стоит "1", а где конец отрезка "-1". Например: отрезки [0;1],[0;2],[1;2]
Полученные массивы: A: 0 0 1 1 2 2 
                    B: 1 1 1 -1 -1 -1.
Нужно отсортировать массив А по возрастанию(не забывая при этом также и о массиве В). Если в массиве А начало и конец отрезков имеют одну и ту же координату, то начало отрезка должно идти левее. 
 Написал сортировку с помощью Быстрой. Но проблема возникла с условием "Если в массиве А начало ... левее". Не знаю, как это учесть в Быстрой сортировке. Помогите-а.
вот код.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void swap(int* a, int i, int j, int* b) {
    int t = a[i];
    a[i] = a[j];
    a[j] = t;

    int x = b[i];
    b[i] = b[j];
    b[j] = x;
}
void qs_helper(int* a, int l, int r,int*b) {
    if (r > l) {
        int i, j, k, pe;
        int m = (l + r) / 2;
        if (a[l] < a[m]) {
            if (a[m] < a[r])swap(a, l, m, b);
        }
            else if (a[l] < a[r])swap(a, l, r,b);
            else if (a[r] < a[m])swap(a, l, m,b);
            else if (a[r] < a[l])swap(a, l, r,b);
        pe = a[l];
        i = l;
        j = l + 1;
        k = r;
        while (j <= k)
            if (a[j] == pe) {
                if (b[j] > b[i]) {
                    int v = b[j] ;
                    b[j] = b[i];
                    b[i] = v;
                }
        j++;
    }
            else if (a[j] < pe) { swap(a, i, j,b); j++; i++; }
            else if (a[j] > pe) { swap(a, j, k,b); k--; }
        qs_helper(a, l, i - 1,b);
        qs_helper(a, k + 1, r,b);
    }
}
void quick_sort(int*a,int n,int*b) {
    qs_helper(a,0,n-1,b);
}
int main()
{
    int n; cin >> n;
    int*a = new int [2*n];
    int*b = new int[2*n];

    for (int i = 0; i < 2*n; i++)   cin >> a[i];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)      b[i] = 1;
    for (int i = n; i < 2 * n; i++)    b[i] = -1;

    quick_sort(a, 2*n, b);
    cout << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < 2 * n; i++)   cout<<a[i]<<" ";
    cout << endl<<endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 2 * n; i++)   cout << b[i] << " ";


    delete[] a;
    delete[] b;
}






 while (j <= k)
            if (a[j] == pe) {
                if (b[j] > b[i]) {
                    int v = b[j] ;
                    b[j] = b[i];
                    b[i] = v;
                }
        j++;
```

вот тут надо что-то добавить

Comment: А зачем вообще писать свою сортировку? Стандартная не устроит? Сохраняем сразу в вектор пар, и сортируем...

Comment: @Harry,  Наверное для прибретения навыков

Comment: @ARHovsepyan Все равно хранить в двух массивах - плохое решение...

Answer (score 2):

Если пользоваться всем стандартным, то, как я понимаю, можно вот так:

```
int main()
{
    unsigned int n;
    cin >> n;
    vector<pair<int,int>> v;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 2*n; i++)
    {
        int x;
        cin >> x;
        v.push_back(make_pair(x,(i<n)?1:-1));
    }
    sort(v.begin(),v.end(),[](const pair<int,int>& a,
                                const pair<int,int>& b)
           {
               return
                   (a.first < b.first) ? true :
                   (a.first > b.first) ? false :
                   (a.second > b.second) ? true : false;
           });

    for(auto x: v)
        cout << x.first << "(" << x.second << ")  ";

    cout << endl;


}
```